# Second Order Stochastic Dominance and $\Pr[X<Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X$ be a random variables with continuou cdf $F$ in the support $[a,b]$.  Let $Y$ be another r.v. with cdf $G$, which is continuous in $[a,b)$ and has an atom at $b$.  $X$ and $Y$ are independent. We also have $E[X]=E[Y]$ and second order stochastic dominance

$$\int_a^k F(t)\,dt \leq \int_a^k G(t)\,dt, \  \ \  a \leq k \leq b.$$

Can we say the following:

$$\Pr[X \leq Y] \leq \frac 1 2 \text{?}$$

My attempt:  I have tried numerical analysis with different parameter values and the above statement is always true. However, it gets difficult to prove it analytically.

Comment: Is there some independence assumption? Otherwise it seems you could take $X=F^{-1}(1-G(Y))$ and probably have a contradiction. (The inverse denotes the quantile function.)

Comment: @Ian Thanks, missed the independence assumption